# How can I change the page's URL when a visitor clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

When a visitor clicks a button element, how can I change the URL?

Example:

```
<form id="search">
  <input type="text" />
  <button onclick="javascript:alert('hi');">Alert Hi</button>
  <button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'">Go to Google</button>
</form>
```

([Or see JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7UEe/).)

For a quick demo page, I just need to send the visitor to a new URL when they click a button.  I can execute JavaScript onclick (in the Alert Hi button), and the URL changes if I execute `window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'` from Firebug's console.  What do I need to do to change the URL on a button click?

Comment: Your buttons submit the form. Also since you have a fiddle you should know that Google won't load in a frame because of `X-frame-options`

Comment: So an anchor tag just won't suffice?

Comment: @Shmiddty - I know! In this case, the button is nicely styled, but the page is in a half built state as I'm waiting on some specs from a stakeholder, so we're faking it.

Comment: @KatieK See the newest updates to my answer about making it work without JS

Comment: @KatieK I love the windows shortcuts tips on your webpage, I didn't know about shift+right click for extra options

Comment: @JuanMendes Cool, glad to hear it was helpful  FWIW, I have an RSS feed at http://www.pewpewlaser.com/pplb.rss.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that the form is being submitted when you click on the button. Add `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form. You also don't need `javascript` in the `onclick` attribute. See [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Example http://jsfiddle.net/E7UEe/1/ Notice that it won't go to google.com because jsfiddle has disallowed it. Notice the error message `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

```
<form id="search">
  <input type="text" />
  <button onclick="javascript:alert('hi');">Alert Hi</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'">Go to Google</button>
</form>​
```

An alternative that works without JS is the `appearance:button` [CSS directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance) http://jsfiddle.net/d6gWA/

```
<a class="btn"> Link looking like button</a>​
.btn {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -ms-appearance: button;
}​
```

Or you could always put the button in a link http://jsfiddle.net/d6gWA/2/

```
<a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button type="button">Link Button</button></a>​
```

Comment: Is a button assumed to be a submit button?

Comment: Yes http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/button.html `A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to "submit".`

Answer (score -1):

```
 <button onclick="javascript:window.location='http://www.google.com/'">Go to Google</button>
```

just remove your .href and it sould work